# How do I scan/enumerate vst plugin dlls?

Tags: dll, audio, vst

I'm trying to build a small program that hosts vst effects and I would like to scan a folder for plugin dlls.
I know how to find all the dlls but now I have the following questions:

- What is the best way to determine if a given dll is a vst plugin?
  I tried to just see if the ddl exports the proper function and this works fine for plugins made with the more recent versions of the vst sdk since it exports a method called "VstPluginMain" but older versions export a rather generic "main" function.
- How do I determine if the plugin is an effect or an instrument?
- How do I scan vst shell plugins?
  Shell plugins are basically dlls that somehow contain multiple effects. An example of this are the plugins made by Waves Audio http://www.waves.com/

ps: If there is a library that can do all of this for me please let me know.

Comment: Would you be willing to share some of your host code? Trying to create a vst host myself, no idea where to start.

Comment: @DanielRodrigues I have an open-source VST host at http://github.com/teragonaudio/MrsWatson/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How to determine a VST plugin?

Once you've found main/VSTPluginMain... call it!
If what's returned is NULL, it's not a VST.
If what's returned is a pointer to the bytes "VstP" (see `VstInt32 magic; ///< must be #kEffectMagic ('VstP')` in aeffect.h), then you have a VST.

The VSTPluginMain returns a pointer to an AEffect structure. You will need to look at this structure.

Effect or instrument? `AEffect::flags | (effFlagsIsSynth = 1 << 8)`

Shell VSTs are more complex:

Category will be kPlugCategShell

Support the "shellCategory" canDo.

Use effShellGetNextPlugin to enumerate.

To instance, respond to audioMasterCurrentId in your callback with the ID you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
There's just something that I don't fully get.
Let's assume I find a dll that's not a plugin but exports "main" (which seem a pretty common name...) and then returns something from it. Am I not going to be in trouble if I try to dereference that value looking for "VstP"?

Comment: Potentially. You would certainly check to see if the pointer was nonzero. You might also consider checking to see if your callback was called.

It would make little sense for a user to have stored a malicious DLL in their VSTPlugIns folder.

Comment: @DaveGamble Yea, my main concern was malicious code. Good answer!

Answer (score 3):

@Dave Gamble nailed it, but I wanted to add a few things on VST shell plugins, since they are a bit tricky to work with.

To determine if a VST is a shell plugin, send the `effGetPlugCategory` opcode to the plugin dispatcher. If it returns `kPlugCategShell`, then it's a shell plugin. To get the list of sub-plugins in the shell, you basically call `effShellGetNextPlugin` until it returns 0. Example code snippit (adapted from a [working VST host](http://github.com/teragonaudio/MrsWatson/)):

```
// All this stuff should probably be set up far earlier in your code...
// This assumes that you have already opened the plugin and called VSTPluginMain()
typedef VstIntPtr (*Vst2xPluginDispatcherFunc)(AEffect *effect, VstInt32 opCode, VstInt32 index, VstIntPtr value, void *ptr, float opt);
Vst2xPluginDispatcherFunc dispatcher;
AEffect* plugin;
char nameBuffer[40];

while(true) {
  memset(nameBuffer, 0, 40);
  VstInt32 shellPluginId = dispatcher(pluginHandle, effShellGetNextPlugin, 0, 0, nameBuffer, 0.0f);
  if(shellPluginId == 0 || nameBuffer[0] == '\0') {
    break;
  }
  else {
    // Do something with the name and ID
  }
}
```

If you actually want to load a plugin in a VST shell, it's a bit trickier. First, your host needs to handle the `audioMasterCurrentId` opcode in the host callback. When you call the VST's `VSTPluginMain()` method to instantiate the plugin, it will call the host callback with this opcode and ask for the unique ID which should be loaded.

Because this callback is made *before* the main function returns (and hence, before it delivers an `AEffect*` to your host), that means that you probably will need to store the shell plugin ID to load in a global variable, since you will not be able to save a pointer to any meaningful data in `void* user` field of the `AEffect` struct in time for it to be passed back to you in the host callback.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop your VST Host application in .NET take a look at [VST.NET](http://vstnet.codeplex.com)